# System.Linq.IQueryable Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC (an older version) application and I need to create a form to find reservations based on two parameters: Date and RoomID. There are underlying tables in the database: ReservationRequests and Rooms linked by RoomID.

I wrote this query in the Repository:

```
public IQueryable<ReservationRequest> FindReservationRequestInfo(DateTime date, int roomID)
    {
        return from requests in FindAllReservationRequests()
                where requests.Date == date

                    & requests.RoomID == roomID

                select requests;
    }
```

The Model looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace RoomReservations.Models
{
    public class FindReservationRequestInfo
{
    public IQueryable<string> ReservationRequestsInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public SelectList Rooms { get; set; }

    public FindReservationRequestInfo(IQueryable<string> reservationRequestsInfo, DateTime date, SelectList rooms)
    {
        ReservationRequestsInfo = reservationRequestsInfo;
        Date = date;
        Rooms = rooms;
    }
}
```

}

And the code in the Controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using RoomReservations.Models;
using RoomReservations.Helpers;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc;


namespace RoomReservations.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    IRepository Repository;

    public ReportsController()
        : this(new Repository())
    {
    }

    public ReportsController(IRepository repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }


    //
    // GET: /Reports/FindReservationRequestInfo
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult FindReservationRequestInfo()
    {
        IEnumerable<Room> rooms = Repository.FindAllRooms();
        rooms = rooms.Concat(new List<Room>() { new Room() }.AsEnumerable()).OrderBy(o => o.ID);

        return View(new FindReservationRequestInfo(
            new List<string>().AsQueryable(), DateTime.Today,
            new SelectList(rooms, "ID", "Name")));
    }

    //
    // POST: /Reports/FindReservationRequestInfo
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize(Roles = "Administrator"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult FindReservationRequestInfo(FormCollection collection)
    {
        IQueryable<string> reservationRequestsInfo;
        DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

        Room room = Repository.GetRoom(Convert.ToInt32(collection["ID"]));

        if (collection["Date.Date"] == String.Empty)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Date.Date", "Date is required");



        if (ModelState.Sum(s => s.Value.Errors.Count()) == 0)
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(collection["Date.Date"]);

            if (room == null)
            {
                room = new Room();
                reservationRequestsInfo = Repository.FindReservationRequestInfo(date, room.ID);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            reservationRequestsInfo = new List<string>().AsQueryable();
        }

        IEnumerable<Room> rooms = Repository.FindAllRooms();
        rooms = rooms.Concat(new List<Room>() { new Room() }.AsEnumerable()).OrderBy(o => o.ID);

        return View(new FindReservationRequestInfo(
            reservationRequestsInfo, date,
            new SelectList(rooms, "ID", "Name", room.ID)));
    }
 }
```

}
        //

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code in the Controller. I will be very grateful if somebody could help me to understand what I did wrong.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Change IQueryable<string> reservationRequestsInfo; to IQueryable<ReservationRequest> reservationRequestsInfo; in the controller

Comment: Thank you! I change it, but it still gives me an error in the `reservationRequestsInfo = new List<string>().AsQueryable();` line and in the `return View(new FindReservationRequestInfo(
                reservationRequestsInfo, date,
                new SelectList(rooms, "ID", "Name", room.ID)));`part in the Controller's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning

```
IQueryable<ReservationRequest>
```

but in your controller you're setting it equal to a variable that you declare as

```
IQueryable<string>
```

so this bit

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize(Roles = "Administrator"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult FindReservationRequestInfo(FormCollection collection)
    {
        IQueryable<string> reservationRequestsInfo;
        //...
```

should be

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize(Roles = "Administrator"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult FindReservationRequestInfo(FormCollection collection)
    {
        IQueryable<ReservationRequest> reservationRequestsInfo;
        //...
```

and then refactor appropriately for cascading effects of the change.

Comment: Thanks! I made this change from  IQueryable<string> reservationRequestsInfo to IQueryable<ReservationRequest> reservationRequestsInfo. But now I have another error in the last part of the code in the Controller:

Comment: I cannot format the code correctly:
`else
            {
                reservationRequestsInfo = new List<string>().AsQueryable();
            }

            IEnumerable<Room> rooms = Repository.FindAllRooms();
            rooms = rooms.Concat(new List<Room>() { new Room() }.AsEnumerable()).OrderBy(o => o.ID);
`
The error is in the line 'reservationRequestsInfo = new List<string>().AsQueryable();'

Comment: And in the last segment:
`return View(new FindReservationRequestInfo(
                reservationRequestsInfo, date,
                new SelectList(rooms, "ID", "Name", room.ID)));
        }`

Comment: Again, you've already declared `reservationsRequestInfo` as `IQueryable<ReservationRequest>`.  You cannot implicity convert that to an `IQueryable` (or `List`) of `string`.

Comment: I made changes from '<string>' to '<ReservationRequest>, as you advised in the Model, as `public class FindReservationRequestInfo
    {
        public IQueryable<ReservationRequest> ReservationRequestsInfo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        
        public SelectList Rooms { get; set; }

        public FindReservationRequestInfo(IQueryable<ReservationRequest> reservationRequestsInfo, DateTime date, SelectList rooms)
        {
            ReservationRequestsInfo = reservationRequestsInfo;
            Date = date;
            Rooms = rooms;
        }
    }`

Comment: And in Controller. But again I'm getting an Error: "Use of unassigned local variable 'reservationRequestsInfo': `IEnumerable<Room> rooms = Repository.FindAllRooms();
            rooms = rooms.Concat(new List<Room>() { new Room() }.AsEnumerable()).OrderBy(o => o.ID);

            return View(new FindReservationRequestInfo(
                reservationRequestsInfo, date,
                new SelectList(rooms, "ID", "Name", room.ID)));`
Please help me to understand my mistake! Thank you very much!

Comment: Assign the variable some value when you declare it. Something like IQueryable<ReservationRequest> reservationsRequestInfo = null;

Comment: Thank you very much for being so patient with me!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to take a look one more time at the original code in the 'Model' and in the Repository that I posted above to suggest what's wrong there. When I'm debugging I'm getting an Error message: 'RoomReservations.Models.Repository' does not implement interface member 'RoomReservations.Models.IRepository.FindReservationRequestInfo(System.DateTime, RoomReservations.Models.Room)'.
I'm running a query on the 'ReservationRequests' table and using a 'Rooms' table in the Controller to create a dropdown list on the form. Thank you!

Comment: That means your concrete repository is missing the specified method.  An interface is a contract that must be followed by it's implementations, so if you implement an interface, you *have* to implement all of it's methods.

Comment: I do have this method in the IRepository:
`IQueryable<ReservationRequest> FindReservationRequestInfo(DateTime date, int roomID);`. Is it correct with the current Repository & Model? Thank you so much!

Comment: No.  Read the error *carefully*.  Your interface is asking for a method that accepts a `Room` object.  You are implementing one that accepts an `int roomID`.

Comment: I guess, I stuck with the Controller now. The idea was to get a reservation request from one table 'ReservationRequest" based on two parameters: 'date' and 'RoomID'. I needed a 'room.ID' field from another table 'Rooms' to use as a dropdown list of available rooms on the form. I thought that the Model and the query in Repository were correct, as well as the IRepository. But in the Controller I don't have any reference to the 'RoomID' parameter, just to room.ID as a part of the 'SelectList (rooms...).
I'm very new to the asp.net mvc, would it be possible for you to suggest where i messed up?